# Simple Replace function not working with degree symbol

Tags: vba, excel

If I try this -

```
Replace("±1°", "°", vbNullString)
```

Result is as expected.
However, I'm extracting data from another workbook, so it's stored in a variable. So, when I run -

```
Replace(ToleranceLabel, "°", vbNullString)
```

it never works. Then I tried with the 'Chr' function.

```
Replace(ToleranceLabel, Chr(176), vbNullString)
```

still didn't work.
I wanted to verify that the text I was getting the unicode symbol for decimal number 176 and not the unicode using the decimal number 186 for degree. I checked the decimal number and I get 176.

I tried different compare methods, vbTextCompare vs vbBinaryCompare. I still cannot get it to replace the text.

Using InStr to see if it can even find the symbol and it cannot find the degree symbol.

It must be something simple. I'm hoping any of you geniuses might be able to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `ToleranceLabel` in your `Replace` function?

Comment: Does `Asc(Right(ToleranceLabel,1))` return `176`? This part isn't very clear to me: *I wanted to verify that the text I was getting the unicode symbol for decimal number 176 and not the unicode using the decimal number 186 for degree. I checked the decimal number and I get 176.*

Comment: When you say "Doesn't work" does that mean your extracted data, after running through the code still contains `±1°` when it should have them all replaced by `°`?

Comment: This works exactly as expected when I try to run it. Can you show more of your code? In particular, the assignment of `toleranceLabel` **AND** the portion of code where you believe the text has not been properly replcaced? (so far you've shown us the statement that should do replacing, and indicated it does not work -- but you have not shown us how you arrive to that conclusion).

Comment: @Kyle - the ToleranceLabel is the ±1° in this case.

Comment: @Mat's Mug - I was thinking maybe I was getting the (Alt+0186) rather than the (Alt+0176). Wanted to make sure that I was getting value of 176.

Comment: @FreeMan - yes, the extracted data should have replaced the ° but did not

Comment: @David Zemens it does work exactly as the first one I demonstrate, but when I get the value ±1° into the variable it doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with @DavidZemens, you need to [edit] your question and add the assignment of `toleranceLabel` and all the relevant code. As it stands it's not really possible to give you an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand exactly what is in the cell.  Click on the cell and run:

```
Sub WhatIsInThere()
    Dim i As Long, msg As String
    msg = Len(ActiveCell.Value) & vbCrLf
    For i = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Value)
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & i & vbTab & Mid(ActiveCell.Value, i, 1) & vbTab & AscW(Mid(ActiveCell.Value, i, 1))
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Then you can decide how to process the cell.

Comment: So, that's what I did first, was check the `Asc()` of the cell and got 176. Now, I used your function but it's giving me 8304. I realize that it's using the `AscW()` function. So, I guess I must look into that more.

Comment: Thanks! 

As a resolution, I needed to use `Replace(ToleranceLabel, ChrW(8304), vbNullString)` in order to find and replace the correct value.

Comment: **You must be careful.**  *Asc()* may lie, but *AscW()* should always tell the truth!

Comment: Lesson Learned the hard way! Thanks again!

Comment: Well explained answer